# How to parse JSON with Flutter in the background correctly?

Tags: json, dart

I am doing my first steps with Flutter and struggling with the JSON parsing.

I have started with the cookbook for [fetching data](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data). Everything was fine with my own JSON. Then I switched to the [background parsing](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/background-parsing) (as it is more useful), cookbook example worked but as soon as I try to switch to my own JSON I get the following error.

```
flutter: Exception: NoSuchMethodError: 
Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'cast' with matching arguments.
Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:6
Tried calling: cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()
Found: cast<Y0, Y1>() => Map<Y0, Y1>
```

My JSON dart model is generated with the help of quicktype.io and as it is good in the "fetching data" example, I think there is just an issue caused by my JSON format compared to the "background parsing" cookbook example.

I have found similar issues on stackoverflow but the solutions like `cast<String, dynamic>` did not work. I know the error is within `final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();` but I do not know how I can make it fit my own JSON structure.

Would appreciate any help :)

Coding:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  final response = await client
      .get(Uri.parse('https://my-json-url')); //exists of course, just hidden

  // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
  return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
}

// A function that converts a response body into a List<Photo>.
List<Photo> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Photo>((json) => Photo.fromJson(json)).toList();
}


class Photo {
  Photo({
    required this.errMsg,
    required this.errCode,
    required this.responseId,
    required this.api,
    required this.version,
    required this.data,
  });

  final String errMsg;
  final String errCode;
  final String responseId;
  final String api;
  final String version;
  final PhotoData data;

  factory Photo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Photo(
    errMsg: json["err_msg"],
    errCode: json["err_code"],
    responseId: json["response_id"],
    api: json["api"],
    version: json["version"],
    data: PhotoData.fromJson(json["data"]),
  );
}

class PhotoData {
  PhotoData({
    required this.success,
    required this.data,
  });

  final bool success;
  final DataData data;

  factory PhotoData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PhotoData(
    success: json["success"],
    data: DataData.fromJson(json["data"]),
  );
}

class DataData {
  DataData({
    required this.results,
    required this.total,
  });

  final List<Result> results;
  final int total;

  factory DataData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DataData(
    results: List<Result>.from(json["results"].map((x) => Result.fromJson(x))),
    total: json["total"],
  );
}

class Result {
  Result({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.alias,
    required this.introtext,
    required this.fulltext,
    required this.catid,
    required this.state,
    required this.created,
    required this.modified,
    required this.publishUp,
    required this.publishDown,
    required this.images,
    required this.access,
    required this.featured,
    required this.language,
    required this.hits,
    required this.createdBy,
    required this.tags,
  });

  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String alias;
  final String introtext;
  final String fulltext;
  final Catid catid;
  final String state;
  final DateTime created;
  final DateTime modified;
  final DateTime publishUp;
  final String publishDown;
  final Images images;
  final String access;
  final String featured;
  final String language;
  final String hits;
  final CreatedBy createdBy;
  final Tags tags;

  factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Result(
    id: json["id"],
    title: json["title"],
    alias: json["alias"],
    introtext: json["introtext"],
    fulltext: json["fulltext"],
    catid: Catid.fromJson(json["catid"]),
    state: json["state"],
    created: DateTime.parse(json["created"]),
    modified: DateTime.parse(json["modified"]),
    publishUp: DateTime.parse(json["publish_up"]),
    publishDown: json["publish_down"],
    images: Images.fromJson(json["images"]),
    access: json["access"],
    featured: json["featured"],
    language: json["language"],
    hits: json["hits"],
    createdBy: CreatedBy.fromJson(json["created_by"]),
    tags: Tags.fromJson(json["tags"]),
  );
}

class Catid {
  Catid({
    required this.catid,
    required this.title,
  });

  final String catid;
  final String title;

  factory Catid.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Catid(
    catid: json["catid"],
    title: json["title"],
  );
}

class CreatedBy {
  CreatedBy({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
  });

  final String id;
  final String name;

  factory CreatedBy.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CreatedBy(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
  );
}

class Images {
  Images({
    required this.imageIntro,
    required this.floatIntro,
    required this.imageIntroAlt,
    required this.imageIntroCaption,
    required this.imageFulltext,
    required this.floatFulltext,
    required this.imageFulltextAlt,
    required this.imageFulltextCaption,
  });

  final String imageIntro;
  final String floatIntro;
  final String imageIntroAlt;
  final String imageIntroCaption;
  final String imageFulltext;
  final String floatFulltext;
  final String imageFulltextAlt;
  final String imageFulltextCaption;

  factory Images.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Images(
    imageIntro: json["image_intro"],
    floatIntro: json["float_intro"],
    imageIntroAlt: json["image_intro_alt"],
    imageIntroCaption: json["image_intro_caption"],
    imageFulltext: json["image_fulltext"],
    floatFulltext: json["float_fulltext"],
    imageFulltextAlt: json["image_fulltext_alt"],
    imageFulltextCaption: json["image_fulltext_caption"],
  );
}

class Tags {
  Tags({
    required this.typeAlias,
    required this.itemTags,
  });

  final dynamic typeAlias;
  final List<dynamic> itemTags;

  factory Tags.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Tags(
    typeAlias: json["typeAlias"],
    itemTags: List<dynamic>.from(json["itemTags"].map((x) => x)),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "typeAlias": typeAlias,
    "itemTags": List<dynamic>.from(itemTags.map((x) => x)),
  };
}


void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const appTitle = 'Isolate Demo';

    return const MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Photo>>(
        future: fetchPhotos(http.Client()),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            print (snapshot.error);
            return const Center(
              child: Text('An error has occurred!'),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return PhotosList(photos: snapshot.data!);
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PhotosList extends StatelessWidget {
  const PhotosList({Key? key, required this.photos}) : super(key: key);

  final List<Photo> photos;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // just placeholder widgets so far
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: photos.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
              elevation: 8.0,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Stack(children: <Widget>[
                    // Container(
                    //   height: 200.0,
                    //   child: Ink.image(
                    //     image: NetworkImage(photos[index].thumbnailUrl),
                    //     fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    //   ),
                    // ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      // alignment workaround
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 150.0),
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                      child: Text("Text",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            //fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.orange)),
                    )
                  ]),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text("Here we can place some kind of preview text"),
                  )
                ],
              ));
        });
    //Text();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```dart
jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()
```

to

```dart
jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<String, dynamic>()
```

to make it not *throw*.
Then, because that's an unnecessary operation, change it to

```dart
jsonDecode(responseBody) as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

The `cast` method on collections are used to cast the *elements* (keys and values for maps). It's not the same as doing an `as` cast on the collection itself.

Here, the value of `jsonDecode` is a `Map<String, dynamic>`, but with static type `dynamic`. What you want is an `as` cast to that type.

(Or, if you actually thought the decoded JSON was a `List<dynamic>` containing `Map<String, dynamic>` values, then your code is correct, but the incoming JSON source doesn't match your assumption. You'll have to figure out why. Be sure you know the structure of the JSON you decode, the type of the result depends on that.)